# Does the Stopwatch affect bosses?

Tags: castlevania-circle-of-the-moon

I've been using the Stopwatch to give me an advantage in some harder areas, but I recently tried it against the Iron Golem boss and time didn't slow at all. Does the Stopwatch not affect bosses in general? Are there other points in the game when it does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the stopwatch does not work on bosses.

From the [StrategyWiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Castlevania:_Circle_of_the_Moon/Weapons#Stopwatch):

> Don't bother trying to use this against bosses

Another source is [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/449471-castlevania-circle-of-the-moon/faqs/12820) guide on GameFaqs:

> The real downside to it is that it doesn't stop time while facing Bosses,
>   nor does it stop time in the Battle Arena.

So the conclusion is that there are 2 events where it doesn't work on enemies:

- Bosses
- Battle Arena

Comment: Damn back to holy water I go!